# how to get all row from second table againt a single record and merge as column sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to fetch records from a table and for each records if there is an entry in second table get all multiple rows, if exists, and show as a column with first one.
e.g. if we select products from a table and each product have multiple images in images table. i want to get all distinct products and join images and show all images as column not as row.
i am trying like this:

```
select img.product_image,prod.product_id,prod.product_name
from tbl_Product prod 
left outer join tbl_image img on img.product_id = prod.product_id
```

like below image if there is an image entry in images table then it should come after prod_id, like image1 | image2 | image3
not as rows as showing in image.

Comment: You want a `PIVOT` query. look for sample in internet.

Comment: i checked PIVOT but i want to convert rows of second table into columns not first one to make them distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think it may help you


create procedure sp_Select_Product
(
@iproductid int
)
As
/*
Exec sp_Select_Product 1
*/
if exists(select product_id from tbl_Product where product_id=@iproductid)
begin
select distinct product_image from tbl_image where product_id=@iproductid
end
```

Comment: :-( no boss. also it is not for a single product for all products.